# missing shared library in ldd

Tags: gcc, libraries

I compiled Apache httpd on CentOS 6.x. Works fine there.

Then I moved the binary files to CentOS 7. I needed to install some missing libraries and now works fine there.

Then I moved the binary files to Archlinux. As I expected it did not started directly:

```
httpd: symbol lookup error: /software_pack/httpd-2.2.25/lib/libapr-1.so.0: undefined symbol: dlopen
```

However, if I do `ldd /software_pack/httpd-2.2.25/lib/libapr-1.so.0` it gives different results on CentOS and Archlinux. On Archlinux, libdl.so is not shown at all?

Where from CentOS knows the file needs libdl.so.2 ?

CentOS 6.x:

```
# ls -la /software_pack/httpd-2.2.25/lib/libaprutil-1.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Jul 30 09:47 /software_pack/httpd-2.2.25/lib/libaprutil-1.so.0 -> libaprutil-1.so.0.5.2
# ldd /software_pack/httpd-2.2.25/lib/libaprutil-1.so.0.5.2
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffec400000)
        libexpat.so.0 => /software_pack/httpd-2.2.25/lib/libexpat.so.0 (0x00007f5ec94d8000)
        libapr-1.so.0 => /software_pack/httpd-2.2.25/lib/libapr-1.so.0 (0x00007f5ec92a8000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f5ec9098000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f5ec8e60000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5ec8c40000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5ec88a8000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5ec9928000)
        libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007f5ec8630000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5ec8428000)   <<<<<<<< Missing in arch
```

On Archlinux:

```
# ls -la /software_pack/httpd-2.2.25/lib/libaprutil-1.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Jul 30 10:47 /software_pack/httpd-2.2.25/lib/libaprutil-1.so.0 -> libaprutil-1.so.0.5.2
# ldd /software_pack/httpd-2.2.25/lib/libaprutil-1.so.0.5.2
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff7cdd3000)
        libexpat.so.0 => /software_pack/httpd-2.2.25/lib/libexpat.so.0 (0x00007f5aef4e7000)
        libapr-1.so.0 => /software_pack/httpd-2.2.25/lib/libapr-1.so.0 (0x00007f5aef2ba000)
        librt.so.1 => /usr/lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007f5aef084000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /usr/lib/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f5aeee4b000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5aeec2d000)
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5aee87f000)
        /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5aef934000)
```

Comment: Does `libapr-1.so.0` link to `libapr-1.so.0.4.8`? It looks like you are running `ldd` on different files.

Comment: yes "bundled" apr, located in apache's lib directory (same file)

Comment: For consistency, update the output so that it shows exactly same file on both systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dlopen` is normally provided by `libdl.so.2`. On Arch Linux `libdl.so.2` is provided by `glibc` package. It would be very strange if you didn't have `glibc` installed, but anyway, check if you have `libdl.so.2` on your system.

You can also use `readelf` command to output a symbol table for a shared object and check if particular symbol is exported:

```
readelf -Ws /usr/lib/libdl.so.2
```

Some info on why `ldd` output for the same binary may differ on different systems can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714219/ldd-different-output-same-binary-different-distros

Comment: I am marking your answer as correct. The real way I fixed the thing was to delete all libapr-1 files from apache bundled directory (e.g. /software_pack/httpd-2.2.25/lib/ ). This made linker to link with "real" apr files from /lib64 directory.

Comment: May I ask why you deploy it this way? Is it a customized apache build?

Comment: I made this build for my CentOS servers, but I want to be able to run it on my Archlinux too. It is full "stack" - nginx, apache, php5.2, pho5.4, mariadb, redis.